# Using iText 7, what's the proper way to export a Flate encoded image?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am trying to create code to export out the images within a PDF using iText Version 7.19.  I'm having some issues with Flate encoded images. All the Flate encoded images from the Microsoft free book I'm using as an example (see [Moving to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/09/13/free-ebook-moving-to-microsoft-visual-studio-2010/)) always coming out pink and depending upon how I try to copy the bytes they can come out distorted.

If I attempt to copy all the image bytes at once (see the SaveFlateEncodedImage2 method in the code below), they come out distorted like this one:

[image]

If I attempt to copy them row by row (see the SaveFlateEncodedImage method in the code below), they are pink like this one

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using to export them:

```
using iText.Kernel;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Filters;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ITextPdfStuff
{
    public class MyPdfImageExtractor
    {
        private readonly string _pdfFileName;

        public MyPdfImageExtractor(string pdfFileName)
        {
            _pdfFileName = pdfFileName;
        }

        public void ExtractToDirectory(string directoryName)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(_pdfFileName))
            {
                // Avoid iText.Kernel.Crypto.BadPasswordException: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065052/97803
                reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);

                using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
                {
                    ExtractImagesOnAllPages(pdfDoc, directoryName);
                }
            }
        }


        private void ExtractImagesOnAllPages(PdfDocument pdfDoc, string directoryName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of pdf {pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPdfObjects()} objects");

            // Extract objects https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/extracting-objects-pdf
            for (int objNumber = 1; objNumber <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPdfObjects(); objNumber++)
            {

                PdfObject currentObject = pdfDoc.GetPdfObject(objNumber);

                if (currentObject != null && currentObject.IsStream())
                {
                    try
                    {                 
                        ExtractImagesOneImage(currentObject as PdfStream, Path.Combine(directoryName, $"image{objNumber}.png"));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Object number {objNumber} is NOT an image! -- error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ExtractImagesOneImage(PdfStream someStream, string fileName)
        {
            var pdfDict = (PdfDictionary)someStream;
            string subType = pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Subtype)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

            bool isImage = subType == "/Image";

            if (isImage == false)
                return;

            bool decoded = false;


            string filter = pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Filter).ToString();

            if (filter == "/FlateDecode")
            {
                SaveFlateEncodedImage(fileName, pdfDict, someStream.GetBytes(false));
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] imgData;

                try
                {
                    imgData = someStream.GetBytes(decoded);
                }
                catch (PdfException ex)
                {
                    imgData = someStream.GetBytes(!decoded);
                }

                SaveNormalImage(fileName, imgData);
            }

        }

        private void SaveNormalImage(string fileName, byte[] imgData)
        {
            using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgData))
            using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream))
            {
                image.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                Console.WriteLine($"{Path.GetFileName(fileName)}");
            }
        }

        private void SaveFlateEncodedImage(string fileName, PdfDictionary pdfDict, byte[] imgData)
        {
            int width = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Width).ToString());
            int height = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Height).ToString());
            int bpp = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.BitsPerComponent).ToString());

            // Example that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517377/97803
            PixelFormat pixelFormat;
            switch (bpp)
            {
                case 1:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                    break;
                case 24:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bpp);
            }

            // .NET docs https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_filters_1_1_flate_decode_strict_filter.html
            // Java docs have more detail: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.7/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/filters/FlateDecodeFilter.html
            imgData = FlateDecodeStrictFilter.FlateDecode(imgData, true);
            //  byte[] streamBytes = FlateDecodeStrictFilter.DecodePredictor(imgData, pdfDict);

            // Copy the image one row at a time
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat))
            {
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);

                int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * bpp / 8.0);
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                    int offset = i * length;
                    int scanOffset = i * bmpData.Stride;
                    Marshal.Copy(imgData, offset, new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt64() + scanOffset), length);
                }

                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"FlateDecode! {Path.GetFileName(fileName)}");
        }


        /// <summary>This method distorts the image badly</summary>
        private void SaveFlateEncodedImage2(string fileName, PdfDictionary pdfDict, byte[] imgData)
        {
            int width = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Width).ToString());
            int height = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.Height).ToString());
            int bpp = int.Parse(pdfDict.Get(PdfName.BitsPerComponent).ToString());

            // Example that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517377/97803
            PixelFormat pixelFormat;
            switch (bpp)
            {
                case 1:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                    break;
                case 24:
                    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bpp);
            }

            // .NET docs https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_filters_1_1_flate_decode_strict_filter.html
            // Java docs have more detail: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.7/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/filters/FlateDecodeFilter.html
            imgData = FlateDecodeStrictFilter.FlateDecode(imgData, true);
            // byte[] streamBytes = FlateDecodeStrictFilter.DecodePredictor(imgData, pdfDict);

            // Copy the entire image in one go
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat))
            {
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
                Marshal.Copy(imgData, 0, bmpData.Scan0, imgData.Length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"FlateDecode! {Path.GetFileName(fileName)}");
        }
    }
}
```

The code can be instantiated and called like this from within a .NET Core console application:

```
  string existingFileName = @"c:\temp\ReallyLongBook1.pdf";
  var imageExtractor = new MyPdfImageExtractor(existingFileName);
  imageExtractor.ExtractToDirectory(@"c:\temp\images");
```

I'm running the following free Microsoft book through this code:
[Moving to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/09/13/free-ebook-moving-to-microsoft-visual-studio-2010/)

The image in question is on page 10 and it's black and white (not pink).

I'm no PDF expert and I've been banging on this code for a couple of days now picking apart a number of examples to try to piece this together.  Any help that would get me past my pink images, would be greatly appreciated.

-------Update Feb 4, 2020------

Here is the revised version after MKL's suggested changes.  His change extracted more images than mine and produced proper looking images that appear in the book I mentioned above:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ITextPdfStuff
{
    public class MyPdfImageExtractor
    {
        private readonly string _pdfFileName;

        public MyPdfImageExtractor(string pdfFileName)
        {
            _pdfFileName = pdfFileName;
        }

        public void ExtractToDirectory(string directoryName)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(_pdfFileName))
            {
                // Avoid iText.Kernel.Crypto.BadPasswordException: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065052/97803
                reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);

                using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
                {
                    ExtractImagesOnAllPages(pdfDoc, directoryName);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ExtractImagesOnAllPages(PdfDocument pdfDoc, string directoryName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of pdf {pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPdfObjects()} objects");

            IEventListener strategy = new ImageRenderListener(Path.Combine(directoryName, @"image{0}.{1}"));
            PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
            for (var i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(i));
            }
        }
    }


    public class ImageRenderListener : IEventListener
    {
        public ImageRenderListener(string format)
        {
            this.format = format;
        }

        public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
        {
            if (data is ImageRenderInfo imageData)
            {
                try
                {
                    PdfImageXObject imageObject = imageData.GetImage();
                    if (imageObject == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Image could not be read.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format(format, index++, imageObject.IdentifyImageFileExtension()), imageObject.GetImageBytes());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Image could not be read: {0}.", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
        {
            return null;
        }

        string format;
        int index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you work on the raw data and don't use the itext parsing framework?

Comment: @mkl I'm not sure I follow.  Is there an easier way to do this?  itext documentation is NOT great and I can't seem to find any .NET C# examples doing this.  I've found some that dump the files as raw data, but none that export them as images.  The things I do find are really old and the library has changed a lot between iText 5 and 7. Also, if there are other .NET PDF libraries that aren't super expensive that can do this, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: *"Is there an easier way to do this?"* - yes, you can use the parsing framework (more often used to extract text but indeed also featuring access to bitmap and vector graphics). When I'm back in office next week, I can write an answer explaining in more detail.

Comment: @mkl When you get a chance, I'd still be interested any any suggestions.

Comment: I still have marked your question. Unfortunately I had marked a number of questions, so I have not been able to look into all of them yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFs internally support a very flexible bitmap image format, in particular as far as different color spaces are concerned.

iText in its parsing API supports export of a subset thereof, essentially the subset of images that easily can be exported as regular JPEGs or PNGs.

Thus, it makes sense to try and export using the iText parsing API first. You can do that as follows:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"extract\");
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"Moving to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ebook.pdf"))
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader))
{
    IEventListener strategy = new ImageRenderListener(@"extract\Moving to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ebook-i7-{0}.{1}");
    PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
    for (var i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(i));
    }
}
```

with the helper class `ImageRenderListener`:

```
public class ImageRenderListener : IEventListener
{
    public ImageRenderListener(string format)
    {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (data is ImageRenderInfo imageData)
        {
            try
            {
                PdfImageXObject imageObject = imageData.GetImage();
                if (imageObject == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Image could not be read.");
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format(format, index++, imageObject.IdentifyImageFileExtension()), imageObject.GetImageBytes());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Image could not be read: {0}.", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        return null;
    }

    string format;
    int index = 0;
}
```

In case of your example document it exports nearly 400 images successfully, among them your example image above:

[image: "Moving to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ebook-i7-16.png"]

But there also are less than 30 images it cannot export, on standard out you'll find "Image could not be read: The color space /DeviceN is not supported.."

Comment: Your way extracted more images than mine as well.  I got 318 images and your way result in 399.  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidYates some of those extra images may be duplicates. The code in my answer exports each *use* of an image. An image used multiple times, therefore, is exported multiple times.

Comment: Any other possibilities to extract the masked PNG images from PDF document. The provided solution works for normal JPEG and PNG images, but masking is not applied for masked PNG images.

Comment: You can export the mask bitmap separately and apply it using the graphics library of your choice.